# Код javascript внутри комментария кода Java

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

В проекте на jav'e встретил странный код:

```
public static native void initNative()
/*-{
какой то код на javascript
}*/;
```

и главное все работает! Понимаю, что гэвэтэвские дела, но не думал, что это работает таким образом, объясните, что за технология?

Comment: и как отлаживать такой javascript?

Comment: Больше подробностей. Что за проект( с технической точки ), отрывок чуть более развернутого кода..ибо компиляция JavaScript по-разному может протекать.

Comment: Понял, что это JSNI (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html), интересно, мне одному кажется это каким-то извращением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [JavaScript Native Interface (JSNI)](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.JavaScriptNativeInterface.html), применяется в GWT для использования кода написанного на JavaScript.

Позволяет написать собственный JavaScript и использовать его в клиентской части Java кода. Например, функциональность самого низкого уровня некоторых основных классов GWT написаны на JavaScript.

Написание и использование JSNI методов является мощной техникой, но следует использовать с осторожностью. JSNI код является менее кроссбраузерным, большая вероятность утечки памяти, меньше поддается Java-инструментам и является непростой задачей для оптимизации компилятором.

**JSNI предоставляет такие возможности как:**

- выполнение Java методов непостредственно в JavaScript
- оборачивание безопасных Java методов вокруг существующих JavaScript
- вызов JavaScript в Java коде и наоборот
- чтение и запись Java полей из JavaScript
- использование debug режима как для Java так и для JavaScript(скриптовый отладчик)

JSNI методы объявляются как native и содержат JavaScript код в спец. формате блока комментариев, который начинается с /*-{ и заканчивается */-} . 
JSNI методы называются также как и любые методы Java. Синтаксис JSNI является директивой для Java к JavaScript компилятору для принятия любого текста между заявленным блоком комментариев как правильный JavaScript код и внедряет его в созданные GWT файлы. Во время компиляции GWT компилятор выполняет некоторую проверку синтаксиса JavaScript кода внутри метода, затем генерирует код интерфейса для преобразования аргументов метода и возвращаемых значений.

Простой пример JSNI метода, который выводит JavaScript диалоговое окно:

```
public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
    $wnd.alert(msg);
}-*/;
```

Обратите внимание, что код не ссылается на объект JavaScript окна непосредственно внутри метода. При обращении к окну браузера и объектам документа из JSNI, вы должны ссылаться на них как $wnd и $doc соответственно. Этот скомпилированный скрипт работает во вложенном фрейме, $wnd и $doc автоматически инициализируются правильно ссылаясь на окно и документ хостовой страницы. 
Посмотрим на другой пример, который возбуждает исключение:

```
public static native int exampleThrewException() /*-{
    return "not a number";
}-*/;
try {
    int value = exampleThrewException();
    GWT.log("We got a value " + value, null);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    GWT.log("JSNI method exampleThrewException() threw an exception", ex);
}
```

Этот пример компилируется как Java, а его синтаксис проверяется GWT компилятором как валидный JavaScript. Но если запустить пример в режиме разработки он выбросит след. исключение.

```
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.HostedModeException: Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method '@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.WebStorageGwtApp::exampleThrewException()': JS value of type string, expected int
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JsValueGlue.getIntRange(JsValueGlue.java:266)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JsValueGlue.get(JsValueGlue.java:144)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeInt(ModuleSpace.java:247)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeInt(JavaScriptHost.java:75)
    …....
```

В этом случае, ни Java IDE, ни GWT компилятор не скажет вам, что существует несоответствие между типом кода внутри JSNI метода и Java декларацией. Сгенерированный код интерфейса на GWT поймал проблему в рантайме в режиме разработки. При запуске кода в рабочем режиме исключение увидеть не можно, т.к. динамическая типизация JavaScript скрывает проблемы такого рода.

**Как получить доступ к Java-методам и полям из JavaScript?**

Бывает очень полезно манипулировать Java объектами в пределах JavaScript реализации JSNI метода. Но, поскольку JavaScript использует динамическую типизацию, а Java использует статическую типизацию, вы должны использовать специальный синтаксис.

**Вызов Java-методов из JavaScript**

Вызов Java-методов из JavaScript похожа на вызов Java-методов из C в JNI. JSNI заимствует JNI подход сигнатуры метода для различения перегруженных методов. Вызовы JavaScript в Java методах имеет след. вид:

```
[instance-expression]@class-name::method-name(param-signature)(arguments)
```

- instance-expression - должен присутствовать при вызове метода экземпляра и должен отсутствовать при вызове статического метода
- class-name - полное имя класса в котором объявляется метод
- param-signature - внутренняя сигнатура Java метода определенная в JNI Type Signatures, но без задней сигнатуры возвращаемого типа метода, т.к. в нем нет необходимости при выборе перезагрузки
- arguments - список аргументов для передачи в вызываемый метод

**Вызов Java конструктора из JavaScript**

Сравним на примере Java выражения против JSNI выражений:

```
class Main {
    public Main() {/** */}
    public Main(int i) {/** */}

    static class StaticInner {
        public StaticInner() {/** */}
    }

    class TestInner {
        public TestInner(int i) {/** */}
    }
}
```

- *new Main()* equals
   @com.webstorage.gwt.client.Main::new()()
- *newStaticInner()* equals
   @com.webstorage.gwt.client.Main.StaticInner::new()()
- *mainInstance.new TestInner(135)* equals
   @com.webstorage.gwt.client.Main.TestInner: :new(Lcom/dmitrynikol/webstorage/gwt/client/Main;I)(mainInstance,135)

**Доступ к Java полям из JavaScript**

Рассмотрим на примере доступ к статическим полям и полям экземпляра класса из JSNI:

```
class JSNI {
    String instanceField = "test";
    static double staticField = 12345;

    public void instanceMethod(String value) {
        /** just use 'value' */ Window.alert("execute instanceMethod");
    }

    public static void staticMethod(String value) {
        /** just use 'value' */ Window.alert("execute staticMethod");
    }

    /**
     * different situation of accessing Java fields from JavaScript by JSNI
     */
    public native void execute(JSNI jsni, String value) /*-{
        // call instance method runInstanceMethod() on this
        this.@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::instanceMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(value);

        // call instance method runInstanceMethod() on jsni
        jsni.@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::instanceMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(value);

        // call static method staticMethod()
        @com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::staticMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(value);

        // read instance field on this
        var valueFromInstanceField = this.@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::instanceField;
        $wnd.alert(valueFromInstanceField);

        // write instance field on jsni
        jsni.@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::instanceField = value + " value";
        $wnd.alert(jsni.@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::instanceField);

        // access to static field (without qualifier as you can see)
        $wnd.alert(@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::staticField + 1);
    }-*/;
}
```

**Вызов Java метода из JavaScript**

Иногда необходимо получить доступ к методу или конструктору определенному в GWT во внешнем JavaScript коде. Этот код может быть написанный вручную и включен в другой js файл или это может быть частью сторонней библиотеки. В этом случае, GWT компилятор не сможет создать интерфейс между пользовательским JavaScript кодом и сгенерированным JavaScript через GWT напрямую. Эту взаимосвязь можно выполнить назначив метод через JSNI как внешний, глобально видимое JavaScript имя, которое может ссылаться на написанный вручную JavaScript.

```
.....
public static int recalculate(int period, float rate, int overtime) {
    /** ... */
}

public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
    $wnd.count = $entry(@com.dmitrynikol.webstorage.gwt.client.JSNI::recalculate(IFI));
}-*/;
.....
```

Следует обратить внимание на то, что ссылка на экспортируемый метод была завернута в вызов метода **$entry**. Эта ф-ция гарантирует, что Java-производный метод выполняется с неперехваченным установленным обработчиком исключений.

При инициализации приложения просто нужно вызвать **ClassName.exportStaticMethod()** из стартовой GWT точки. Это позволит присвоит ф-цию переменной в окне объекта наз. count.

Параметры и возвращаемые типы JSNI методов объявлены как Java типы. Посмотрим на картинке конкретные правила того, как значения проходящие в и из JSNI кода должны быть обработаны.

[image]

**Исключения и JSNI**

Исключения могут быть брошены во время выполнения любого нормального Java кода или JavaScript кода в JSNI методе. Когда исключение генерируется в JSNI методе оно распространяется вверх по стеку вызова и улавливается в Java catch блоке. Выброшенное JavaScript исключение заворачивается в объект JavaScriptException в то время, когда оно было поймано. Этот объект обертки содержит только имя класса и описание исключения JavaScript, которое произошло. Рекомендуется обрабатывать JS исключения в JS коде, а Java исключения в Java коде. Java исключения могут безопасно сохранять идентичность распространяющихся через JSNI методы.

Например:

1. Java метод **firstExecute()** вызывает JSNI метод **nativeMethod()**
2. **nativeMethod()** внутри вызывает Java метод **secondExecute()**
3. а **secondExecute()** бросает исключение

Исключение из *secondExecute()* будет распространятся через *nativeMethod()* и может быть поймано в *firstExecute()* методе. Исключение будет сохранять свой тип и идентификацию.

(Материал взят тут: [Разбираемся в GWT JavaScript Native Interface (JSNI)](http://dmitrynikol.blogspot.ru/2012/01/gwt-javascript-native-interface-jsni.html) )